# What would the name of this organic compound be?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

[image: Compound]

I am a little lost in naming this compound.

I think it would be something like 2 bromo 4 methylene pentene??

Is that close?

It is a five carbon chain, so pentane, with a Br on carbon two, a methylene substituent on carbon 4, and a alkene on carbon 1.

Comment: 2-Bromo-4-methylpenta-1,4-diene

Comment: Perhaps you could [edit] this to show how it was arrived at? Whilst it may be the correct answer, its not really helping the OP learn anything, and certain not of help to anyone else looking to follow and apply this to similar molecules.

Comment: It is reasonably self-explanatory: keep the double bonds in the chain, alphabetical order in the substituents [switch Br and Me is still understandable] Both double bonds located.